# Laravel 5.1 - using ajax to print a comment, and then being able to instantly delete it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

I'm making a function where I can place a comment and it will show up without refreshing the page (so using AJAX).

This works fine, however users also need to be able to delete comments. when the page get's refreshed they can delete it, however I can't seem to find a way to delete the newly placed comment without refreshing the page.

Incase it's unclear I'll add a scenario

**This currently works:**

> 1)  User adds new comment
>
> 2)  New comment shows via AJAX
>
> 3)  Users refreshes the page
>
> 4) User can delete his comment

**This currently doesn't work:**

> 1)  User adds new comment
>
> 2)  New comment shows via AJAX
>
> 3) user changes his mind and wants to delete the comment (without having refreshed the page first)

Is there anyway I can pick the ID of the newly placed comment and then delete it? I can't find a way.

Here's my current Ajax code, as soon as one comment get's deleted (anywhere) it doesn't work, so there is something wrong with my logic (I know what). But I can't seem to find out the right way

**Ajax Code**

*Var Teller is just a regular counter*

```
$("#details-comment-btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var functionType = "comment";
    var articleid=$('input[name=articleId]').val();
    var owner_id=$('input[name=owner_id]').val();
    var first_name=$('input[name=owner_first_name]').val();
    var last_name=$('input[name=owner_last_name]').val();
    var token=$('input[name=_token]').val();
    var commentBody = $('textarea[name=commentBody]').val();
    var profilepicture = $('input[name=owner_profilepic]').val();
    var commentid = parseInt($('input[name=last_comment_id]').val());

    if(commentBody.length != 0)
    {
        $.ajaxSetup({headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:articleid,
            data:
            {
                'user_id': owner_id,
                'commentBody': commentBody,
                'functionType': functionType,
                'article_id': articleid,
                '_token': token
            },
            success: function(){
                teller ++;
                console.log(articleid);
                $('#newcomment')
                        .prepend('<div class="comment" id="newCommentDiv' + teller + '">');
                    $("#newCommentDiv" + teller)
                            .append('<img  src="/profilePics/'+ profilepicture+ '"  class="profilepicture" >')
                            .append('<a href="/user/'+ owner_id +'/' + first_name + '/' + last_name + '" class="user">' + first_name + " " + last_name + '</a>')
                            .append('<span class="date">Just Now</span>')
                            .append('<p class="body">'+ commentBody + '</p>')
                            .append('<form id="deleteCommentForm'+ teller +'" action="" method="post" role="form">')

                            $("#deleteCommentForm" + teller)
                                .append(' <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="' + token + '">')
                                .append('<input type="hidden" name="articleId" value="' + articleid + '">')
                                .append('<input type="hidden" name="commentId" value="' + (commentid+teller) + '" >')
                                .append('<input type="submit" class="btn" name="remove_comment" id="comment-delete-btn" value="Remove">')

                    $("#newCommentDiv" + teller)
                            .append('</form>');

                $('#newcomment').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and here's the query I use to get ***last_comment_id*** ofcourse I realize that when one comment get's deleted it skips a number, so the ID that get's printed in the form isn't correct anymore.

```
$lastcomment = DB::table('comments')
    ->max('id');
```

Any ideas how I can solve my faulty logic, and get this thing working?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to send the ID of the new comment from Laravel back to the client when the comment is created, and save it somewhere on the client side (in an element's ID, for example).

Then, the AJAX call to delete the comment will be able to send the comment ID with it, so you can look up the comment by ID in Laravel to delete it.